# Reducing size of ODE system by using symmetries: examples, references help request.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, lie-algebras, examples-counterexamples, symmetry

We know:

1. A high order differential equation can be expressed as an ODE system.
2. Knowledge of a symmetry allow one to reduce the order of a differential equation.

So if we do $n$-order ODE $\stackrel{2}{\longrightarrow}$ $(n-1)$-order ODE$\stackrel{1}{\longrightarrow}$ we end up with an ODE system with $n-1$ equations. This suggests we can use symmetries to reduce the number of equations in *some* ODE systems. 
This may sound trivial since we know we can use symmetries to solve ODEs but I'm looking for references, examples, etc... where one uses symmetries in a system of ODEs to obtain a smaller system (not necessarily solve the system).

Answer (score 0):

Of course, knowing a symmetry makes it possible to reduce an ODE system to a system with less components. You may wish to look into, say, Chapter 2 of the book *Applications of Lie groups to differential equations* by Peter Olver, for details.